# Launching a webpage in browser from an Adobe Air app not working

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe

I've got a webpage I want to hook in to my Adobe Air app. It's running JavaScript, so I can't open it in the app, but I'm trying to launch it in the default system browser.

Here's the code that's supposed to be launching the page:

```
        public function beginModule():void {
        var loader:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
        var gameURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("file:///path/to/file.html");
        loader.navigateInSystemBrowser = true;
        loader.load(gameURL);
    }
```

I've also tried using
    flash.net.navigateToURL(gameURL);
but that had no effect.

Every time I hit the above method, that block executes but nothing happens other than a quick cursor change-- no browser opened, no change in the app. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Before you start, check if the HTML page is properly running in the browser.

To open a HTML page in flex, use the HTML tag: `<mx:HTML></mx:HTML>`

Something like this: https://snipt.net/anishnair/flex-show-html-page/?key=28838d54ac287180032dee000ce33a74

Thank you.

Regards,
Anish

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
navigateToURL(url,"_blank");
```

to navigate to the url in the web-browser.